# Callback function on every set event on the webpage

Tags: javascript

For instance, I have an animation, I play it with setInterval. When an event that I previously set on the webpage happens I want a callback function to be fired to call clearInterval. Curious if there is any way to setup such callback function for all events existing in the webpage. Because otherwise I will have to go over every event I set previously. In form of code I am interested in something like that:

```
const i = setInterval(function() {
    //do something
}, 50);

AdditionalCallbackForEveryEventSet(function() {
    clearInterval(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, but wanted to clean up any listeners when a custom component was removed from the DOM (hence, me using `.call()`). It might be a bit too complex for you, but what I want to point out is that you need to build a functionality that you need to use instead of setting the interval/listeners with `setInterval/addEventListener` directly.

**Some Examples**

*Add listener*
`FXListenerBehavior.setListener.call(window, 'aKeyToDiffentiate', functionName);`

*Remove listener*
`FXListenerBehavior.clearListener.call(window, 'aKeyToDiffentiate', functionName);`

*Add interval*
`const TIME_IN_MILLIS = 2000;`
`FXListenerBehavior.setInterval.call(window, 'aKeyToDiffentiate', functionName, TIME_IN_MILLIS);`

*Remove all intervals and listeners*
`FXListenerBehavior.clearAllIntervals.call(window);`

*Print all listeners and intervals*
Nice when debugging.
`FXListenerBehavior.printAll.call(window);`

*Remove all listeners and intervals*
`FXListenerBehavior.clearAll.call(window);`

```js
FXListenerBehavior = {

  /* === SET AND UPDATE === */

  /**
   * @description sets a listener
   * @param {String} name any descriptive name
   * @param {function} method the function to be run with the listener
   * @param {setOnElement} Boolean if the listener should be set on the element or default to window
   * @return {Boolean} true if set, false if listener already exist
   */
  setListener: function(name, method, setOnElement) {
    if (FXListenerBehavior._alreadyExist.call(this, name)) {
      var elementName = FXListenerBehavior._getElementName.call(this);

      console.warn(elementName + '\"' + name + '\" already exist. Use updateListener() if you\'re unsure if the listener exists');

      return false;
    }

    return FXListenerBehavior._setListener.call(this, name, method, setOnElement);
  },

  /**
   * @description sets an interval
   * @param {String} name any descriptive name
   * @param {function} method the method to be repeated
   * @param {Integer} time repeats method after this many milliseconds
   * @return {Boolean} true if set, false if listener already exist
   */
  setInterval: function(name, method, time) {
    if (FXListenerBehavior._alreadyExist.call(this, name)) {
      var elementName = FXListenerBehavior._getElementName.call(this);

      console.warn(elementName + '\"' + name + '\" already exist. Use updateInterval() if you\'re unsure if the interval exists');

      return false;
    }

    return FXListenerBehavior._setInterval.call(this, name, method, time);
  },

  /**
   * @description replaces a listener or interval, or creates one if it doesn't exist
   * @param {String} name any descriptive name
   * @param {function} method the method to be run
   * @param {Integer} time repeats method after this many milliseconds (only for intervals)
   * @return {Boolean} always true
   */
  update: function(name, method, time) {
    if (time > 0) {
      return FXListenerBehavior.updateInterval.call(this, name, method, time);
    } else {
      var setOnElement = time;
      return FXListenerBehavior.updateListener.call(this, name, method, setOnElement);
    }
  },

  updateListener: function(name, method, setOnElement) {
    FXListenerBehavior.clearListener.call(this, name);
    return FXListenerBehavior._setListener.call(this, name, method, setOnElement);
  },

  updateInterval: function(name, method, time) {
    FXListenerBehavior.clearInterval.call(this, name);
    return FXListenerBehavior._setInterval.call(this, name, method, time);
  },

  _setListener: function(name, method, setOnElement) {
    if (name == undefined || method == undefined) {
      traceDebug('name or method is undefined', name, method)
      return
    }

    this._listenersAndIntervals[name] = method;

    if (setOnElement) {
      this.addEventListener(name, method, {
        'passive': true
      });
    } else {
      window.addEventListener(name, method, {
        'passive': true
      });
    }

    return true;
  },

  _setInterval: function(name, method, time) {
    if (name == undefined || method == undefined) {
      traceDebug('name or method is undefined', name, method)
      return
    }

    var intervalId = setInterval(method, time);
    this._listenersAndIntervals[name] = intervalId;
    return true;
  },

  _alreadyExist: function(name) {
    if (typeof this._listenersAndIntervals === 'undefined') {
      this._listenersAndIntervals = {};
    }

    if (this._listenersAndIntervals[name]) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },


  /* === GET AND PRINT === */


  getAll: function() {
    return Object.keys(this._listenersAndIntervals);
  },

  printAll: function() {
    if (this._listenersAndIntervals) {
      var isPolymer2Element = this.is == 'function';
      let elementName = (isPolymer2Element) ? this.is() : this.is;

      console.info("All listeners and intervals for " + elementName + ":\n" + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(this._listenersAndIntervals)));
    }
  },


  /* === CLEAR === */


  /**
   * @description clears a listener
   * @param {String} name any descriptive name, previously set with setListener
   */
  clearListener: function(name) {
    if (FXListenerBehavior._alreadyExist.call(this, name)) {
      window.removeEventListener(name, this._listenersAndIntervals[name])
      delete this._listenersAndIntervals[name];
    }
  },

  /**
   * @description clears an interval
   * @param {String} name any descriptive name, previously set with setInterval
   */
  clearInterval: function(name) {
    if (FXListenerBehavior._alreadyExist.call(this, name)) {
      clearInterval(this._listenersAndIntervals[name]);
      delete this._listenersAndIntervals[name];
    }
  },

  clearAllListeners: function() {
    FXListenerBehavior._clear.call(this, 'listener');
  },

  clearAllIntervals: function() {
    FXListenerBehavior._clear.call(this, 'interval');
  },

  clearAll: function(print) {
    if (print) {
      FXListenerBehavior.printAll.call(this)
    }

    FXListenerBehavior._clear.call(this);

    if (print) {
      FXListenerBehavior.printAll.call(this)
    }
  },

  _clear: function(listenerOrInterval) {
    if (typeof this._listenersAndIntervals === 'object') {

      var keys = Object.keys(this._listenersAndIntervals);

      for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (typeof this._listenersAndIntervals[keys[i]] === 'function' && listenerOrInterval !== 'interval') {
          FXListenerBehavior.clearListener.call(this, keys[i]);
        } else if (typeof this._listenersAndIntervals[keys[i]] === 'number' && listenerOrInterval !== 'listener') {
          FXListenerBehavior.clearInterval.call(this, keys[i]);
        } else {
          var elementName = FXListenerBehavior._getElementName.call(this);

          console.warn(elementName + keys[i] + ' is not a ' + (listenerOrInterval || 'listener'));
        }
      }

    }
  },

  _getElementName: function() {
    var elementName = this.is ||  this.tagName || this.nodeName;

    if (!elementName) {
      traceDebug('FXListenerBehavior lacks element information');
    }

    return (this) ? elementName + ': ' : '';
  }
}
```